# ITK compilation with cmake

Tags: c++, itk

I tried to compile a simple *helloWord* **C++** program with `cmake` using the `ITK` library. However I have some difficulties to link with the `ITK` library and my program doesn't work.

I put my program in the attachment. 
[helloWorld programme](http://www.developpez.net/forums/attachments/p184795d1438849564/c-cpp/bibliotheques/itk-compilation-cmake/helloword.zip/)

CMakeLists.txt :

```
project(HelloWorld)

find_package(ITK REQUIRED)
include(${ITK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(HelloWorld HelloWorld.cxx)

target_link_libraries(HelloWorld ${ITK_LIBRAIRIES})
```

HelloWorld.cxx :

```
#include "itkImage.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

  typedef itk::Image< unsigned short, 3 >  ImageType;

  ImageType::Pointer image = ImageType::New();

  std::cout  <<"ITK Hello World !"<< std::endl;

  return 0 ;

}
```

Comment: You should put the error in the question, and possibly some of the most interesting lines of code.

Comment: The error message is very long and I don't know where is located the mistake. That why I share the project with the CMakeLists.txt sorry !

Comment: Put at least the code of the cmakeLists.txt and some clue about the error. I (and I guess many other)  try to answerto a clear question... if it doesn't involve downloading external stuff and try to build things on my system (and maybe the problem is in your environment anyway, impossible to say without error)

Comment: Or, even better,  try with a known simple example http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/HelloInsight

Comment: Thx ! I tried the simple example you give me and it's work ! But it's the same things that my code. I don't know why it didn't work with my code !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld ${ITK_LIBRAIRIES})
```

should be

```
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```